# New record with link-to in Ember?

Tags: ember.js

I want to create a new record, which should belong to an existing one.

So my idea was to use the `link-to` helper and pass it the existing record and create a new one in the corresponding route.

```
{{#link-to "create" this}}create record{{/link-to}}

...

App.CreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function (existing) {
        return this.store.createRecord('mymodel', {
            some    : '',
            data    : '',
            existing: existing
        });
    },

    deactivate: function () {
        this.currentModel.rollback();
    }
});
```

The problem is, when I try to bind the properties of the new record to the create-form template, I get the data of the existing record, not the newly created one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation for the [model](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model) hook in routes. The problem you're experiencing is that the `model` hook *doesn't get called* when you transition to a route using `link-to`. Because you've already given the model as the second parameter to `link-to`, it doesn't need to run.

As a side note, you shouldn't be manipulating data in routes, that's for controllers. Routes should really just be for setting up your controllers and templates.

---

Example of how I handle this pattern:

```
App.CreateRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return getExisting();
    }
});

App.CreateController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    some: '',
    data: '',
    actions: {
        createRecord: function() {
            this.store.createRecord('type', {
                some: this.get('some'),
                data: this.get('data')
            }).save();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh... I saw a tutorial where they called create record in the route... so what is the solution then? I tried to use a normal link, but I cant simply use the id of the existing record, because handlebars creates those metamorph-script-tags anywhere I do this...

Comment: I guess you _could_ it this way, but I prefer to use `existing` as the model for the route, then create the new record in the controller. Wait until the user has supplied all of the required information, _then_ create the new record. I'll update my post with an example.

Comment: ah I tried this first, but I couldn't get the form-data, because it got binded to the existing record.

Comment: Ah, the controller properties get used for binding before the model properties?

Comment: Yeah. The way Ember works out of the box is that it checks the controller for a property first, then if it doesn't find it, it checks the model second. If you explicitly declare properties in the controller, they'll override the model properties. (You can still access model properties using `model.propertyName`.)

Comment: That's a common sticking point for new users of Ember. I think I'm going to submit a pull request to put something in one of the guides about it. Those hidden features are sometime nice, but can sometimes cause headaches.